# How to expand row from datatable programmatically

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to expand row directly from an typescript method, i've try with @viewchild but it doesn't work :

**HTML:**

```
<p-dataTable [value]="array" [responsive]="true" expandableRows="true" #dt
   (onRowClick)="dt.toggleRow($event.data)">
    <template let-test pTemplate="rowexpansion">
        <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-fluid">
            <div class="ui-grid-row">
                Bouh !
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <p-column field="name" header="Vin"></p-column>
    <p-column field="company" header="Year"></p-column> 
</p-dataTable>
<button class="btn" (click)="addComment()">
    <p>add comment</p>
</button>
```

**Typescript:**

```
import { DataTable } from 'primeng/components/datatable/datatable';

export class MyAwesomeComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('dt') datatable : DataTable;

addComment(): void {
    console.log(this.datatable);
    this.datatable.toggleRow(1);
}
```

row doesn't expand, if someone could tell me how to do the same thing that (onRowClick) event do but inside a typescript method, i will be grateful.

[Showcase for another html example](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/rowexpansion)

Comment: why there was a down vote to answers?

Answer (score 10):

There is a [property](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable) `expandedRows` that is an array of all current expanded rows. You should be able to add / remove your row to this list to toggle row expansion.

You will need to have:

```
<p-dataTable [expandableRows]="true" [expandedRows]="expandedItems"></p-dataTable>
```

and

```
expandedItems: Array<any> = new Array<any>();
// expand row
this.expandedItems.pop(this.gridData[rownumber]);
// hide row
this.expandedItems.push(this.gridData[rownumber]);
```

Simple plunker but you get the idea...
https://plnkr.co/edit/Zra8UUMv4XQCv0lbRbMg?p=preview

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i need

Answer (score 4):

There is a toggleRow method at the level of the data table that takes row data, passed as a parameter:

```
<p-dataTable #dt [value]="cars" expandableRows="true"
    (onRowClick)="dt.toggleRow($event.data)">

  <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>

  <ng-template let-car pTemplate="rowexpansion">
    expanded row
    {{ car.brand }}
  </ng-template>

</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer, as this works perfectly and I couldn't seem to easily locate it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another data table or view after last column like below code

```
 <p-dataTable 
                    [value]="reviewPanels">
<p-column [style]="{'width':'35px'}" expander="true" ></p-column>
<p-column  ></p-column>
<ng-template let-cp pTemplate="rowexpansion">

 <p-dataTable 
         [value]="cp.listreviewerlist" >
<p-column></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
</ng-template>
</p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
addComment(): void {
    console.log(this.datatable);
    this.datatable.toggleRow(this.datatable.selection);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this just for toggling purposes (please make sure you have defined [pSelectableRow]="rowData" in your template body.

```
<p-button label="Save" [pRowToggler]="rowData"></p-button>
```

If you needed something more customized, then you can, defined a reference called #dtEntry :-

```
<p-table #dtEntry [columns]="dataEntryColumns" [value]="data.rptSkMimp" 
            selectionMode="single" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" dataKey="txnId">
```

Somewhere in your code - notice we are passing in (rowdata, dtEntry) above

```
<p-button icon="fa fa-fw fa-plus" label="Save" (click)="onRowSave(rowData, dtEntry)"></p-button>
```

You might have the following script in your code to handle onRowSave.

```
onRowSave(rowData:any, dt:any) {   
dt.toggleRow(rowData);
```

}