# resize row length proper using PrimeNG Datatable?

Tags: angular, datatable, angular2-routing, angular4-forms, primeng-datatable

How can i solve this problem I want to resize row length proper using PrimeNG Datatable?
**Now My Data Display Like These**
 [image: [Now My Data Display Like These]

**And I want to change Like These**
[image: And I want to change Like These]

Comment: Could you give a little more detail on what exactly is desired?  Are you wanting it to automatically resize or just be able to resize the columns?  I am assuming automatic, but if you just want them to be resizable, then add resizable to your p-column `<p-column field="foo" header="Foo" `[resizable]="true"`></p-column>`.

Comment: okay. i want if data is long then data shows on new line, like my 2nd image @MapLion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to expand row from datatable programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42838838/how-to-expand-row-from-datatable-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a more elaborate setup, I would recommend utilizing the resizableColumns, expandableRows and expandedRows options on the p-dataTable and set your widths as percentages as well as make your columns manually adjustable (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable); for example, something like:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" [resizableColumns]="true" [expandableRows]="true" [expandedRows]="expandedItems">
    <p-column field="vin" header="Vin" [resizable]="true" [style]="{'width':'20%'}"></p-column>
    <p-column field="year" header="Year" [resizable]="true" [style]="{'width':'30%'}"></p-column>
    <p-column field="brand" header="Brand" [resizable]="true" [style]="{'width':'15%'}"></p-column>
    <p-column field="color" header="Color" [resizable]="true" [style]="{'width':'35%'}"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

For more detail, see this StackOverflow: [How to expand row from datatable programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42838838/how-to-expand-row-from-datatable-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks. but not working my 2nd column data is too big and display in the same line ..

Comment: <p-column field="ProgramTag" header="Program" [resizable]="true" [style]="{'width':'20%'}"></p-column>
            <p-column field="Title" header="Program Name" [resizable]="true" [style]="{'width':'20%'}"></p-column>
            <p-column field="StartDate" header="Start Date" [resizable]="true" [style]="{'width':'20%'}"></p-column>
            <p-column field="EndDate" header="End Date" [resizable]="true" [style]="{'width':'20%'}"></p-column>