# How to group data using RowGroup in PrimeNG?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I've been doing some research and can't find what I'm looking for. Basically, I want to group my data in **ONLY 3 groups** from top to bottom starting from ROOM3 -> ROOM2 -> ROOM1 and I would also like to add 2 buttons to **expand and collapse groups.**

Example:

```
ROOM3
 - Brady, Marsha   busy
 - Davis, Kevin    Ready-1
 .........
 ...............
ROOM1 
 - Steve, Ana      with MA
 - tester
 .........
 ...............
ROOM2
 - Bacon, Anna     with MA
 - Yoga, Martha    with MA
 ...............
 ....................
```

Here's my working code: [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/iUR1dJhjJylxDAEs062Y?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of changing sorting in your example from:

```
sortField="name"
```

to:

```
sortField="room"
```

Here is a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/zD1ZTYT3FIyw1EWKCH34?p=preview).

Comment: that worked! do you know how to change the order of the groups? Example: I want to order of the groups from top to bottom to be like this: ROOM3 ROOM1 and ROOM2

Comment: @progx That's not "ordered". That's random. You can write custom sorting in your component, for instance in ngOnInit(); otherwise, even if you make groups sortable, they will only sort in 3 > 2 > 1 or 1 > 2 > 3 and not 3 > 1 > 2.

Comment: Oh I see, another quick question. Is there a way to add 2 buttons to expand and collapse all groups? if yes, can you please provide a quick help on that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @progx Check this > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42838838/how-to-expand-row-from-datatable-programmatically

Comment: @progx Feel free to create a new question :)